# BASH_SOURCE variable is empty when script is sourced from cron

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a script, at the beginning of which I capture the script path and the folder using BASH_SOURCE variable as below

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME=$(realpath "$BASH_SOURCE")
FILE_DIR=$(dirname "$FILE_NAME")
```

This runs fine when executed from the command line, but fails when sourced from the crontab.

Especially the variable BASH_SOURCE is empty when run from the crontab.

I am trying to source the file rather than executing it.

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: What's your crontab entry look like?

Comment: It looks like this "source $HOME/.bashrc; . <path to the script>". I just source it using "."

Comment: cron's default shell might not be bash. use `bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc; source <path to the script>'`, or, since an interactive bash shell will read .bashrc, you can use `bash -ic 'source <path to the script>'`. Or, add this to your crontab: `SHELL=/bin/bash`

Comment: What's the reason for going with `source` instead of just executing the script?

Comment: @eduffy The reason I source this is because I set the variables and use them is subsequent commands in the same cronjob. For example "source $HOME/.bashrc; . <path to the script>. /bin/bash $FILEPATH >> $LOG_PATH" etc..

Comment: It would be more clear to put the commands into a separate script file, and the cron job would just invoke that script. That would also make it easier for you to control your environment.